# Javascript banner link open in new window

Tags: javascript, window, new-operator

I have a page with a JavaScript code:

http://pastehtml.com/view/1d997i8.html

please view source code

When you open the page a random banner will be displayed. When I click on the banner, i want to open the link on the banner in a new window.

Right now it opens on the same window.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

< a href="somehwere" target="_blank">yay a new window< /a >

You need to set the "target" attribute in the link

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and include the following in the script:

$('a').attr('target','_blank');