# Exist any code to force all external links and banner ads to open in the new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open all banner ads on new window, or from class, example:  classs `.bannerad` open this in new window,

I have this code but this open my page in new window not the ads, i want to open the ads in new window not my page.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var link = location.href;
  $(".bannerad").click(function(){
    window.open(link);
  });
});
</script>
```

**before I asked this question I tried all the codes from these posts**

1. [Javascript banner link open in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013225/javascript-banner-link-open-in-new-window)
2. [window.open with target '_blank' opens a new browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282604/window-open-with-target-blankopens-a-new-browser-window)
3. [target="_blank" vs. target="_new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new)

so i have see more then 10 post but do not help me.

**My question now is... Exist any code javascript or jQuery to force all external links and banner ads to open in the new window? Thanks.**

Comment: Thanks for your spam that help me to mouch.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Include html sample for at least the banner ads (if it's a link can add blank target, otherwise open with js). And yes, your `link` variable is the window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `target=_blank` to them all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".bannerad").attr("target","_blank");
});
```

Comment: thanks fro your help i have try and this code, but is not working! that is Google Adsense maybe that don't allow `"target","_blank"` Thanks

Comment: @Noni Perhaps or maybe they have code that strips all the target=_blank attributes that runs after your code. Also you may want to see if that is against their policies? I have not ever ran into that specific issue.